# Get removed elements in InkCanvas

Tags: wpf, inkcanvas

I was wonder if there was any method in which I can access an element which the user removes. For example when the InkCanvas is set to Select users can select elements and press delete to remove them. Is there any way of getting to this item if they deleted it? Any help is much appreciated.

Cheers,

Nilu

**Update**

@Drew: Not really. Say for example I have an image on the InkCanvas. I have some strokes attached to this image. If the user selects the image and then deletes it, I want the strokes to be removed.

Answer (score 1):

Does handling the [StrokeErasing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.inkcanvas.strokeerasing.aspx) event not give you what you want? You should be able to access the Stroke being erased from the [InkCanvasStrokeErasingEventArgs::Stroke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.inkcanvasstrokeerasingeventargs.stroke.aspx) property.